# Update inventory after purchase

Tags: javascript-objects

I have an array of objects, which means I get multiple items (products) from a database.
And I want to update after a site purchase on all products purchased inventory, download 1 from the 'nimcar' field
I'm probably having trouble accessing the objects.

I arranged the code into a whole code.
This is a process that happens on the last page after payment is received, I want to update the inventory of the products.
The process I presented here is to get from the database where the order name is listed, from a reference field containing the products it purchased, which are in the purchase basket, and the purchase basket has a reference field containing the product ID.
I was thinking about the process of getting the product ID
Hhazmana.muzarim.muzarim._id
Then update the ID to the 'nimcar' -1 field

```
$w.onReady(function () {

    var id = $w("#dynamicDataset").getCurrentItem()._id;
    wixData.queryReferenced("hazmanot", id, "muzarim")
        .then((results) => {
            if (results.items.length > 0) {
                var firstItem = results.items
            console.log(firstItem );

              var myObj, i;
                myObj = firstItem

                for (i in myObj.muzarim) {
                    var id2 = myObj.muzarim
                    // console.log(id2);
                    wixData.get("muzarim", id2)
                        .then((item) => {
                            item.nimcar = Number(item.nimcar - 1)
                            wixData.update("muzarim", item)
                                .catch((err) => {
                                    let errorMsg = err;
                                })
                        });
                }
            } else {

            }
        });
});
```

That's how it prints it for me:

```
0: "{\"muzarim\":\"7c3e8acd-a7a9-4819-b687-8b1ca06a984b\",\"_id\":\"53904a0d-c3b6-4337-b09d-b779fb0aea1e\",\"_owner\":\"ae269d04-1741-4200-bc92-2e27c7d549cd\",\"hazmanot\":\"af7ba985-f2ed-4bcf-a033-51e36b9298c1\",\"_createdDate\":\"2019-11-21T15:05:03.590Z\",\"lakoh\":\"e005f170-edcf-4694-80b7-496ab3534643\",\"_updatedDate\":\"2019-11-21T15:05:03.590Z\",\"sach\":1,\"camut\":1,\"title\":\"בית מזוזה\"}"
1: "{\"muzarim\":\"e29358d3-a74b-410a-8b41-44679f70ad05\",\"_id\":\"05b7540e-85c6-4eaa-b86b-6f4a466ed57e\",\"_owner\":\"ae269d04-1741-4200-bc92-2e27c7d549cd\",\"hazmanot\":\"3cd1eec3-c586-47b2-a1d4-2b4671c0dd2e\",\"_createdDate\":\"2019-08-21T13:43:38.884Z\",\"lakoh\":\"e005f170-edcf-4694-80b7-496ab3534643\",\"_updatedDate\":\"2019-08-21T13:43:38.884Z\",\"sach\":1200,\"camut\":1,\"title\":\"יין הסיומים\"}"
2: "{\"muzarim\":\"17a8e414-aaeb-4b0f-ae49-a4e5107ad132\",\"_id\":\"6fb545da-ac30-4304-92f9-930b49f87039\",\"_owner\":\"ae269d04-1741-4200-bc92-2e27c7d549cd\",\"hazmanot\":\"2894c50d-07e8-467e-b0f5-a37889a99fad\",\"_createdDate\":\"2019-08-21T13:41:19.197Z\",\"lakoh\":\"e005f170-edcf-4694-80b7-496ab3534643\",\"_updatedDate\":\"2019-08-21T13:41:19.197Z\",\"sach\":7200,\"camut\":1,\"title\":\"סט קדושת יצחק\"}"
3: "{\"muzarim\":\"17a8e414-aaeb-4b0f-ae49-a4e5107ad132\",\"_id\":\"a5ac5af4-03ee-4b88-9929-dc69e9dc0e04\",\"_owner\":\"ae269d04-1741-4200-bc92-2e27c7d549cd\",\"hazmanot\":\"993ed276-f7e1-4741-a038-69ad2b50cc91\",\"_createdDate\":\"2019-08-21T13:40:02.242Z\",\"lakoh\":\"e005f170-edcf-4694-80b7-496ab3534643\",\"_updatedDate\":\"2019-08-21T13:40:02.242Z\",\"sach\":7200,\"camut\":1,\"title\":\"סט קדושת יצחק\"}"
```

Comment: 4 things. 1) If you are going to show a block of code please include the closing brackets and parentheses. 2) Please use proper code formatting techniques 3) Please better explain your problem, what is it intended to do, what is it actually doing? 4) Show what the data looks like, the format of the data will make it much easier to understand

Comment: I have compiled this post according to your questions.
Thanks